# Prime ideal on $C^\infty((-1, 1))$ that is properly contained in the prime ideal consisting of all functions whose derivatives are all $0$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Here, all functions are real-valued. Let $R = C^\infty((-1, 1))$ be the ring of $C^\infty$ functions on the interval $(-1, 1) \subset \mathbb{R}$. Let $P \subset R$ be a prime ideal defined by
$$
P = \{ f \in R \mid (\forall n \in \mathbb{N})(f^{(n)}(0) = 0) \}.
$$
I know that $P$ is actually prime.

I am searching for a prime ideal of $R$ that is properly contained in $P$. I guess that the following $P'$ is also a prime ideal of $R$.
$$
P' = \{ f \in R \mid (\exists r > 0)(F_r(f)(x) \in P) \},
$$
where we define
$$
F_r(f)(x) = \begin{cases} f(x)e^{r/x^2}, & x \neq 0, \\\\ 0, & x = 0. \end{cases}
$$
But I don't come up with how to show that $P'$ is prime. Could you tell me how to prove or disprove this? If this is not correct, it will be helpful if you could modify $P'$ to make it prime, thanks.